# qsort using to sort table of objects

Tags: c++, qsort

My program should work like this:

1. Input the number of points that you want to create.
2. For each point write these: name, x-position, y-position
3. Program should count the length from point to origin(0,0), it is counting in function Leng()
4. All parameters are saving in object abc
5. Then I create the table of objects TabOb
6. I want to sort my points from min length between point and origin(0,0), to maximum length between point and origin. I want to do this using qsort function from stdlib.h
   I have an idea to create compare function which helps me to do that but I don’t know exactly how. Can someone help me?

I’ll give you an example of input and output that I want to get at the end:

Input:

```
2

B 6 8

A 9 12

D 3 4
```

output:

```
D 3 4 

B 6 8

A 9 12
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;

class Klasa {
    string name;
    int    x,y;
    double rr,leng;

    Klasa* TabOb;//table of objects
    int t;//number of points
public:
    Klasa(){}
    Klasa(string name, int x,int y) {
        this->name = name;
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->leng = Leng();
    }
    double Leng(){
        double rr, sq;
        rr = x*x + y*y;
        sq = sqrt(rr);
        return sq;
    }

    int     getX() { return x; }
    int     getY(){ return y; }
    string getName() { return name; }
    double getLength(){ return leng; }

    int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        int _a = *(int*)a;
        int _b = *(int*)b;
        if (_a < _b) return -1;
        else if (_a == _b) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    void InputData(){
        cin >> t;

        TabOb = new Klasa[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
            string name;
            int    x, y;
            cin >> name;
            cin >> x;
            cin >> y;
            Klasa abc(name, x, y);
            TabOb[i] = abc;
        }


        qsort(TabOb, t, sizeof(int), compare);

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
            cout << TabOb[i].getName() << " " << TabOb[i].getX() << " " << TabOb[i].getY() << " " << TabOb[i].getLength() << endl;
        }
    }
}wy;

int main() {

    wy.InputData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::sort`?

Comment: Also, I will ask you -- I give you two TabOj objects.  What is your criteria to tell me (and eventually the sort) which item comes before the other item when sorting?  Whatever that is, that is what you code.  Also, `std::sort` makes this much more simpler, as you aren't doing the void* stuff and all that other non-typesafe coding.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you're doing in your `compare` function.  You're sorting `Klasa` objects, but for some reason you casted the type to an int* when it should be casted to a Klasa*.  This doesn't look correct.  That's why using std::sort enforces you to use the correct type, and not do a bogus cast to int* as you're doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the compare function you are casting the parameters as integer whereas they should be of `klasa` type.Next in the compare function you have to calculate the distance of the point from origin which will be the sorting criteria.

```
 int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    Klasa j = *(Klasa*)a;
    Klasa k = *(Klasa*)b;
    int temp1=sqrt(pow((double) j.getX(),2)+pow((double) j.getY(),2));
    int temp2=sqrt(pow((double) k.getX(),2)+pow((double) k.getY(),2));
    if (temp1 < temp2) return -1;
    else if (temp1 == temp2) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

then you should call quicksort as

```
   qsort(TabOb, t, sizeof(Klasa), compare);
```

because again the type is `klasa` and not `int`

lastly you'll have to put your compare function outside your class.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use `qsort` then the following changes would have to be done:

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
 {
    Klasa* obj1 = (Klasa*)a;
    Klasa* obj2 = (Klasa*)b;
    if (obj1->x < obj2->x) 
       return -1;
    else 
    if (obj1->x == obj2->x) 
        return 0;
     return 1;
 }

//...
    qsort(TabOb, t, sizeof(Klasa), compare);
```

The third parameter to `qsort` is the sizeof the item you want to compare.  Also, the compare function is expecting `Klasa*`, not int's, so you casts are all wrong.  The worst part about this is that the compiler didn't say anything to you that the cast wasn't correct.  That's why in C++, `std::sort` should be used.

My compare was simple, so change what you need to compare, as I don't fully understand what you're trying to compare within the Klasa objects.

---

For a comparison to `qsort`, here is usage of `std::sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
bool compare(Klasa& obj1, Klasa& obj2
{
    return obj1.x < obj2.x;
}
//...
TabOb = new Klasa[t];
std::sort(TabOb, TabObj + t, compare);
```

The `compare` function takes two Klasa objects, and returns `true` if obj1 is to occur before obj2 in the sort.  Otherwise `false` is returned.  I did a simple sort criteria, so change `compare` to match your requirements.

Note that there is no typecasting, and that compare either returns `true` or `false`, not 1, 0, and -1.  Using `qsort` in a C++ program is not necessary and IMO shouldn't be recommended.  Instead, always prefer `std::sort` if you're writing C++.  If you're writing `C` code, then that's a different story, as you have little choice but to use `qsort`.

Also, your code has memory leaks.  You can alleviate this by using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` in your code.